# Ratio of area of wall to area of its shadow

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A rectangular vertical wall runs east to west. The sun is $30$ degree east of south and its altitude is $60$ degree. Find the ratio of the area of the wall to the area of its shadow.

**My try:** The length of shadow and wall will be same. Only height of shadow will shorten.
$$\frac{h}{h’}=\tan 60\Rightarrow h’=\frac{h}{\sqrt3},$$
where $h$ is height of wall and $h’$ is height of shadow.
So required ratio is $\sqrt3$

But the answer is $2/1$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need the width of the shadow _perpendicular to the wall_. Your solution would be correct if the sun were due south, but it isn't.

Comment: @TonyK that means shadow will be parallelogram not rectangle .

Comment: Yes of course. Area = base $\times$ (width _perpendicular_ to base)

Comment: Thank you very much.